# Please format code properly

Tags: discussion, markdown, formatting

Recently I've seen a lot of code being formatted as inline style. This is not how it should be done.

### All code should be formatted with one of two styles.

1. If it is just 1 line, with other text around it, use the ` ` formatting, like this:

   `Hello. This is code` and continued sentence.
2. If it is one line, but on its own, it should have 4 spaces before it:

   ```
   Hello. This is code
   ```

   To save adding the 4 spaces to each line manually, highlight your block of code and click the <kbd>**{ }**</kbd> button on the editing toolbar.

   Sometimes the `inline code` is better - if scrollbars are created. For long one liners the `inline code` can better, so it code wraps. I'll leave this up to the reader to use either, depending on what they feel fits - or split the code onto multiple lines and use 3.
3. If it is multi line, use the 4 spaces before each line:

   ```
   Hello.
   This is code
   ```

   To save adding the 4 spaces to each line manually, highlight your block of code and click the <kbd>**{ }**</kbd> button on the editing toolbar.
4. If it's multi line and in a list, indent the code 8 spaces:

   - Hello
   - This is a list

     ```
     Hello
     This is code.
     ```

### How not to do it.

1. Accent (``` `` ```) formatting on a multi-line code block:

   `Hello.
   This is badly formatted code`
2. Quote format (even if you append the 2 spaces):

   > Hello.
   >   This is badly formatted code
3. 2 line breaks between each line:

   ```
   Hello.

   This is badly formatted code
   ```
4. No formatting. Seriously, this is so hard to read. Compare [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259470/252153) with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259471/252153):

   Hello.
   This is badly formatted code
5. HTML tags (`<code>`)

   `Hello.
   This is badly formatted code`

   HTML tags (`<pre>`). It looks okay, but is less nice to edit.

   ```
   Hello.
   This is badly formatted code
   ```
6. Using speech marks

   "Hello. This is badly formatted code"

### Reminder:

All code should be between ` characters (grave accent, often found below the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key), or have 4 spaces at the start of the question.

```
`Only format inline code with this syntax`
```

```
    Format multiline code with this syntax
```

Comment: Good but that would be hard to make new comers to follow such guidelines.

Comment: @SepehrLajevardi I'd recommend linking this into post, so they learn. It's not just guidelines, it is the right way to format.

Comment: It's good to link to the post, but sometimes it's also worth making the edit - if it's a good question/answer with formatting issues